# Overriding Doorkeepers AccessToken Controller does not seem to work in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, oauth, doorkeeper

The responsible code is not environment specific yet it works locally but not in production:

POST request to my app's /oauth/token should redirect to a controller overriding default Doorkeeper Token response as shown in the first route

## routes.rb

```
require 'api_constraints'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  use_doorkeeper do
    controllers :tokens => 'access_token'
  end
  # Other routes
end
```

The above works fine on a local server however in production[Heroku] this seems to be ignored and is instead routed to default doorkeeper class for no apparent reason. Therefore the response with the token does not contain the user id.

REQUEST TO "https://myapp.herokuapp.com/oauth/token"

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: myapp.herokuapp.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: xxxxxxxx
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&email=john%40gmail.com&password=password
```

THIS RETURNS JSON RESPONSE:

```
{
"access_token": "XXXXXX",
"token_type": "bearer",
"created_at": 1466340696
}
```

The same request to "http://localhost:3000/oauth/token" returns

```
{
"access_token": "XXXXXX",
"token_type": "bearer",
"created_at": 1466341435,
"id": 1
}
```

with the correctly included user_id. I'm not sure if there is some kind of a cache issue which makes my production server use the old routes file. I've tried restarting dynos and push further changes to to heroku master however this did not resolve the issue.

## access_token_controller

```
class AccessTokenController < Doorkeeper::TokensController

  # Overriding create action
  # POST /oauth/token
  def create
    response = strategy.authorize
    body = response.body

    if response.status == :ok
      # User the resource_owner_id from token to identify the user
      user = User.where(response.token.resource_owner_id).first rescue nil

      unless user.nil?
        ### If you want to render user with template
        ### create an ActionController to render out the user
        # ac = ActionController::Base.new()
        # user_json = ac.render_to_string( template: 'api/users/me', locals: { user: user})
        # body[:user] = Oj.load(user_json)

        ### Or if you want to just append user using 'as_json'
        body[:id] = response.token.resource_owner_id
      end
    end

    self.headers.merge! response.headers
    self.response_body = body.to_json
    self.status        = response.status

  rescue Doorkeeper::Errors::DoorkeeperError => e
    handle_token_exception e
  end
end
```

Apologies for any confusion and thank you in advance for any assistance with this.

Comment: Are you sure you have the corresponding `User` on your Heroku machine?

Comment: Hi @Uzbekjon , yes I am sure. I can log in with the user account fine, and I can also retrieve the access token via JSON API however only the JSON response on localhost attaches the `id` parameter as it should, heroku just sends the 3 other fields as in the previous implementation of my code.

Comment: @Uzbekjon user was present on the machine however it did not seem to be assigned at  `user = User.where(response.token.resource_owner_id).first rescue nil` thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work at last.

For reasons unknown to me Postgres was not finding the user causing it to be nil and the subsequent if statement `unless user.nil?` was not executed, hence why the resource_owner_id was not attaching. However locally with SQLite3 this was not an issue. I'm sure there is something very basic I'm missing here with development on Heroku or PG in general. I would appreciate any advise, if I find anything myself I'll post it here also.

Working version of the access token controller

```
class AccessTokenController < Doorkeeper::TokensController

  # Overriding create action
  # POST /oauth/token
  def create
    response = strategy.authorize
    body = response.body

    if response.status == :ok
      # Return user id
      body[:id] = response.token.resource_owner_id unless nil
    end

    self.headers.merge! response.headers
    self.response_body = body.to_json
    self.status        = response.status

  rescue Doorkeeper::Errors::DoorkeeperError => e
    handle_token_exception e
  end
end
```